# Update Query in SQL with numeric pattern in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, pattern-matching

Good Day All,

I need assistance in an creating an update query that groups my data.

The data in my table is actually spatial in nature and can be thought of a matrix that is 10 columns by 5 rows.  I have the ObjectID, Row and Column but I want the column DesiredResult which is a 2x2 grouping of the rows & columns.

So the R,Cs of 1,1 1,2, 2,1 and 2,2, will have a DesiredResult of 1 while the 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 will have a DesiredResult of 2 and so on (see below for an example)  ....

I was able to create the R and C columns using a combination of Quotient & Mod so I assume I would do somethign similar but I am stuck.  How would I go about this query in MS Access ?

```
 ObjectID   R   C   DesiredResult
 1            1 1   1
 2            1 2   1
 3            1 3   2
 4            1 4   2
 5            1 5   3
 6            1 6   3
 7            1 7   4
 8            1 8   4
 9            1 9   5
 10           1 10  5
 11           2 1   1
 12           2 2   1
 13           2 3   2
 14           2 4   2
 15           2 5   3
 16           2 6   3
 17           2 7   4
 18           2 8   4
 19           2 9   5
 20           2 10  5
 21           3 1   6
 22           3 2   6
 23           3 3   7
 24           3 4   7
 25           3 5   8
 26           3 6   8
 27           3 7   9
 28           3 8   9
 29           3 9   10
 30           3 10  10
 31           4 1   6
 32           4 2   6
 33           4 3   7
 34           4 4   7
 35           4 5   8
 36           4 6   8
 37           4 7   9
 38           4 8   9
 39           4 9   10
 40           4 10  10
 41           5 1   11
 42           5 2   11
 43           5 3   12
 44           5 4   12
 45           5 5   13
 46           5 6   13
 47           5 7   14
 48           5 8   14
 49           5 9   15
 50           5 10  15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remou had a close approximation but it turns out this gives me what I need.  I needed both a row and a column index.

```
 SELECT ObjectID, R, C, 
   Int(([C]-1)/2) AS ColIndex,
   Int(([R]-1)/2) AS RowIndex, 
   [RowIndex]*5+[ColIndex]+1 AS DesiredResult
 FROM Testing
 ORDER BY ObjectID
```

The key in the query is that there is the number 2 in both the Column & Row Index (which is the grouping size) and the number 5 is used in Desired Result and represents the Number of Row cells.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Something like ... ?

```
SELECT a.Row, a.Col, Col\2 AS D1, Col Mod 2 AS D2, [D1]+[D2] AS Desired
FROM  table  AS a
ORDER BY a.Row, a.Col;
```

Comment: Hi Remou,  Hmm.  The problem is that in my real table, there are 430 columns !  Any ideas to generalize it ?

Comment: Not in Access there are not 430 columns, the maximum number of columns is 255. You mention a grid of 10 x 5, if that is not your set-up, you should provide a more accurate description. For example in MS Access column is used as a synonym for field, what does does column mean to you? What is your schema?

Comment: Ah - you misunderstood me.   I am not actually making a new column, I am holding the resultant value into a Column called DesiredResult.  Since I have 430 columns in my original table, this value should just go from 1-215.

Comment: Where is your original table? If you look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx#_Toc296343503), you will see that the maximum number of fields (columns) in MS Access is 255. Please post your table schema.

Comment: Thanks for your help !  I mis-spoke (mis-typed I guess).  The data are organized into three columns (see above) called ObjectID, Row, Column and the values in the Row *represents* the number of rows of the dataset, the values in Column *represents* the number of columns.  Once I get the column DesiredResult, I will use a join on ObjectID and my GIS to process the DesiredResult column.

Comment: That is much simpler. See the outline above.